# Rest Webservice in magento 1.8

Tags: php, web-services, rest, magento-1.8

I have configured all things by going System->Webservices menu, submenus that start with REST.And then I test in myDomainname/api/rest/, but it shows a 404 error like "Request does not match any route". It is shown the guide tutorial in http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html here, not fully. I need to show all product list/details, customer details. But I can't understand what is next procedure after configuring/setting up as I am new in Web Service.Will I have to create a custom module or page for Magento1.8 Webservice REST or not. I need total step by step procedure after configuring in System->Webservice->REST.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, Magento already has a REST web-service that allows you to retrieve products. When the url domainname/api/rest/products, then it successfully returns the product details in XML format.But I also need to show the list customer details and logged in customer details and sales details and order details in XML format.If any one knows about it, please reply it.